# onbeforeunload problem in chrome

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

I  have implemented unsaved changes warning before tab out to other page. So I need to save the current form before the page unload. I trigger these functions using onbeforeunload event.

```
if(confirm(confirm_msg)) {
    save_data_using_ajax_call(url)
}
```

also I tried

```
if(confirm(confirm_msg)) {
    document.form_name.submit();
    return 'changes saved';
}
```

First method working in Firefox, But not in chrome. In IE8 it get returns before the form has saved. Second method not working in chrome. but works in firefox and IE. Can anyone tell me a consistent way of approach?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1601388/google-chrome-onbeforeunload-wrong-behavior-with-iframe